# How do I grant free weapon expertise in WotC's new Character Builder?

Tags: tools, dnd-4e-character-builder, dnd-4e

In one of the games I run, I grant the players free Expertise as a heroic level power-bump. The players really like the format of the new Character Builder sheets.

While I would like to use the new CB for that reason, I don't see any way to add house-ruled feats. What is the least onerous method for adding * Expertise to the new CB characters?

Comment: IMO it is probably easier for DMs to lower defenses by 1 point per tier

Comment: Yeah, It's a slightly more elegant solution that preserves the actual *benefit* of expertise. Throw that in an answer, please :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**This is now possible.**

I'm not sure when this was changed, but there is now an Orange House icon on the top of both the Powers and Feats tabs.

If you click the Orange house, an extra power or feat slot will be added and can be used for whatever purpose you desire.

If you click on the extra feat slot, there is a remove button at the bottom of the window that pops up. That will delete the extra slot.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can do that within the Character Builder at the moment.

You could work around the problem, as the DM, by lowering defenses by one point per tier.

Then, depending on why you are doing this - I've seen both fixing the to-hit math of the game, and I've seen eliminating a feat tax quoted as reasons - you may want to ban players from taking the feat.